# How can I use WebRTC on desktop application?

Tags: video-streaming, native, desktop-application, webrtc

I want to do video streaming from my desktop application to Chrome or Firefox using WebRTC technology.

So far, I only see many WebRTC tutorials using HTML5 & Javascript coming out which running only on Chrome or Firefox. How about desktop application or native application?

If I want to develop those applications, what is a way or library I can use to realize this?

Comment: None of the above URLs works, here is the updated URL: [http://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/](http://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/)

Answer (score 9):

Native WebRTC libraries:

- WebRTC native APIs (C++) https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/native-apis/
- Pion (Go) https://pion.ly, https://github.com/pion/webrtc/
- RawRTC (C++) https://github.com/rawrtc/rawrtc
- aiortc (Python) https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc
- GStreamer (C) https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html
- webrtc-rs (Rust) https://github.com/webrtc-rs/webrtc
- sipsorcery(C#) https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery

Making into a community wiki.